# Undefined index in php shopping cart page with PDO style connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I trying to create a shopping cart using SESSION with PDO style connection, but I'm facing error

> ***"Notice: Undefined index: name in"***  ***"Notice: Undefined index: price in"***

I'm pretty sure that exists in my database table, here is the code

```
<?php  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * from tbl_product');
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
        {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-4">  
            <form method="post" action="../ppuyakul/cata_main?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">  
                <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                    <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                    <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></h4>
                    <h4 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
                    <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                </div>  
            </form>  
        </div>  
        <?php  
        }
```

Thanks in advance, i really don't know how to solve this issue =(

Comment: print the `$row` by `print_r($row)` & show the output

Comment: are you sure that you have a column `name` in your table `tbl_product` ?

Comment: @AgamBanga Thanks I will try now,

Comment: @hassan yeah very sure  that is already in there =(

Comment: @AgamBanga

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => HP Notebook [image] => 2.jpg [price] => 299.00 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Panasonic T44 Lite [image] => 3.jpg [price] => 125.00 ) )

$ Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => HP Notebook [image] => 2.jpg [price] => 299.00 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Panasonic T44 Lite [image] => 3.jpg [price] => 125.00 ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the function `fetchAll` which returns all the rows at once. You need to fetch the row one by one which can be done via `fetch_row` method of `mysqli`. You should change it from

`while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

to

`while($row = $stmt->fetch_row(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`

**Alternatively**, You can also use `fetchAll` but then you need to store the results in a variable & then loop over that variable like below

```
$all_rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($all_rows as $row)
{
     //do the html part & anything
}
```

Comment: P.S or by using fetchAll and iterating over it using foreach , `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foreach ($rows ...`

Comment: @hassan, yup that is also correct, updated the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You use [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) in you pdo statement, which will return an array. So you need to access by $row[0]['name'], or use

```
foreach($row as $v){
  $v['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code, Thanks, all you guys once again really appreciated

```
<?php  
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * from tbl_product');
                $stmt->execute();
                if($stmt->fetchColumn() > 0) 
                {
                  $all_rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach($all_rows as $row) 
                     {
                ?>  
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <form method="post" action="../ppuyakul/cata_main.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">  
                          <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                               <img src="<?php echo print_r($row)["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                               <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"] ?></h4>  
                               <h4 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>  
                               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />  
                               <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                     }  
                }  
                ?>
```